# How to stage new changes after the initial Git commit?

Tags: git

Honestly I'm not too good with Git and GitHub and I've been mostly using them as a place to store my project in case my PC dies unexpectedly. Usually when I want to commit a project to GitHub I do this:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Message"
git remote add origin "URL of repository"
git push origin master
```

Now I'm wondering how should I stage and commit after that initial commit? Should I do the same, just without the init:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Message"
git remote add origin "URL of repository"
git push origin master
```

Or should my `git add .` become something different?

Comment: `git init` and `git remote add` is not something you have to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once your setup is complete, the only thing you still need to do for committing is:

Stage the files to prepare a commit

```
git add . # stage all files OR
git add path/to/file # stage just one file ...
```

create a commit(s):

```
git commit -m "message"
```

push the commit(s) to your remote (which you already added before, no need to do that again):

```
git push origin master # OR
git push origin <your-branch-name> # if you are on another branch
```

Comment: When I stage files using git add . do I stage all files that have been edited since last commit or do I stage all files, edited and not edited?

Also isn't using git add path/to/file a bit of a hassle? Like you gotta know which files you've changed and which you haven't.

Comment: adding a file which wasn't edited is a no-operation. So adding all, or only the edited files is just the same.

Comment: adding only a certain file is useful if you just want to commit part of your work. You might be interested in learning about `git commit --all` and `git add --patch`. Read about them online, they are nice to know.